# Telerik Extensions DatePicker and JQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, telerik, telerik-mvc

I'm evaluating the Telerik MVC extensions primarily for the Chart functionality.  I'm also using JQuery and JQuery.Ui thoruhgout out app. To get the grid to work I included the Telerik extensions by puting this `@Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)`  However, that seems to include its own version of JQuery which is breaking the JQuery Datepicker on other pages.  Has anoyone else seen this? Or has anyone found anyway to "tell" telerik to not include JQuery and just use the one my app is already including?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line to use your own jQuery

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)))
```

This instructs Telerik to not use the jQuery version that it has installed with the controls but instead uses the version that you have included in your scripts section